# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpCookie' to type 'System.String'.

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm relatively new to C# and cookies but have used them extensively in VB. I've searched and tried many iterations of saving and retrieving cookies using methods from on this site and also on MSDN. My latest issue is an error being thrown telling me I can't convert a type cookie to a string. Below is the code I've used the create the cookie.

```
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
            myCookie["userGUID"] = userGUID;
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

I've also tried:

```
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("userGUID");
            myCookie.Value = userGUID;
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Prior to using the line HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie) the cookie wasn't even being saved.

The code I'm using the retrieve the cookie value is:

```
        string userGUID = "";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["userGUID"] != null)
            {
                userGUID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["userGUID"];
            }
        }
```

I've also tried:

```
        string userGUID = "";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userGUID"] != null)
        {
            userGUID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userGUID"];
        }
```

Both approaches throw the same error:

```
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpCookie' to type 'System.String'.
```

The above code resides in a .cs file - namespace TTS_CommonRoutines, class TTS_Common which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.

At this point it's obvious to me that I must be missing something very simple but I just don't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

You need to fetch the cookies information into a `HttpCookie` reference variable because 'Request.Cookies' returns a `HttpCookie` object but you are trying to assign it to a string that is why you are getting this error. Once you retrieve it in a variable you can use it with its name (which returns string). Please check this MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
 HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
 if(cookie != null)
 {
     userGUID = cookie["userGUID"];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (FIX: [HttpCookieCollection.Get:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ezy11xy2(v=vs.110).aspx) If the named cookie does not exist, this method creates a new cookie with that name)

```
// to send a cookie
var myCookie = Response.Cookies.Get("UserSettings");
myCookie.Values.Add("userGUID", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

// to retrieve 
var myCookie = Response.Cookies.Get("UserSettings");
var userGUID = myCookie.Values["userGUID"];
```